# Finding the right value based on comma separated date and value after @ symbol in python

Tags: python, csv

Python newbie here. I have a dataframe in this kind of format

```
Col_A     String                                       Date
X         1/1/2018@12,01/24/2020@11                    6/14/2019
Y         1/1/2018@13,01/24/2019@15,08/07/2020@17      8/5/2021
Z         1/1/2018@13,01/24/2019@15,08/07/2020@17      1/23/2019
```

Here's what I'm attempting to do

```
Col_A     String                                       Date         Value_I_want
X         1/1/2018@12,01/24/2020@11                    6/14/2019     12
Y         1/1/2018@13,01/24/2020@15,08/07/2020@17      8/5/2021      17
Z         1/1/2018@13,01/24/2019@15,08/07/2020@17      1/20/2019     15
```

Basically the dates mentioned are starting dates for the new value which is followed by the '@' symbol. In the case of the first row in my eg, from 1/1/2018 to 1/23/2020, the value remains 12 but changes to 11 starting on 1/24/2020 onwards.

I'm looking to extract the value that follows the '@' based on the date in the 'Date' column.

The number of values separated by commas can vary for each row. In some rows it can just be a the value without any date or a comma separation.

How exactly do I go about this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Edit:
Adding an edit to clarify my question:
The string is actually a range of dates. Let me just take string on row 2 as an eg:

```
1/1/2018@13,01/24/2020@15,08/07/2020@17
```

What it actually means:

```
Date in string         value
1/1/2018               13
1/2/2018               13
1/3/2018               13
...
1/23/2020              13
1/24/2020              15
1/25/2020              15
...
08/06/2020             15
08/07/2020             17
08/08/2020             17
```

So with the 'Date' column in the dataframe which is a single date, the logic I'm trying to implement is similar to below. (Explaining with line 2 as eg)

```
if 8/5/2021 is between 1/1/2018 and 1/23/2018 then value = 13
else if 8/5/2021 is between 1/24/2019 and 08/06/2020 then value = 15
else if 8/5/2021 is greater than 08/07/2020 then value = 17
```

Comment: But the values extracted don't match the dates at all!!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but you might look into [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). If you can get the values in the `String` column, you can split them on `'@'` and `','` and extract some numbers that way.

Comment: @Anwarvic, Thanks for the comment. I'm not looking to match the exact date. I'm looking to match the value on the date between a range. I've added in an edit to my post. Please do let me know if its clarifies my question

Comment: @nullromo, Thanks for the suggestion. I've added in an edit to my post. does that help in understanding the question better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that will help you. Keep in mind, this assumes a lot about the format of the input data. You will have to build in additional checks if your data is formatted inconsistently. Also, it assumes that the dates in the `string` column strings are sorted in ascending order. And you might have to check on any `<` vs `<=` type bugs because I wasn't quite clear on which date should yield which result.

```py
from datetime import datetime

# a format to use when parsing the dates
date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'

# the columns that were given
string = '1/1/2018@13,01/24/2019@15,08/07/2020@17'
date = '8/5/2019'

def find_result(string, date):
    # the target date
    target_date = datetime.strptime(date, date_format)

    # split the 'string' column
    limits = [x.split('@') for x in string.split(',')]

    # convert the date strings into datetime objects so they can be compared
    limits = list(map(lambda x: (datetime.strptime(x[0], date_format), int(x[1])), limits))

    # binary search to find the right limit
    result = None
    # keep track of the max and min bound, with the test point in the middle
    low_search_index = 0
    high_search_index = len(limits) - 1
    test_index = high_search_index // 2
    # go until the range between max and min is 1
    while(high_search_index - low_search_index > 1):
        # get the date at the test index
        test_date = limits[test_index][0]

        # if the test date is later than the target, repeat with the lower half of the array
        if test_date > target_date:
            high_search_index = test_index
            test_index = low_search_index + (high_search_index - low_search_index) // 2

        # if the test date is earlier than the target, repeat with the upper half of the array
        elif test_date < target_date:
            low_search_index = test_index
            test_index = low_search_index + (high_search_index - low_search_index) // 2

        # if the test date is the target, end early and set the result
        else:
            result = limits[test_index][1]
            break

    # set the result
    if result == None:
        if limits[high_search_index][0] > target_date:
            result = limits[low_search_index][1]
        else:
            result = limits[high_search_index][1]

    return result

# some test dates to try it on
test_dates = ['1/1/2000', '1/1/2018', '1/10/2019', '1/24/2019', '2/10/2019', '8/7/2020', '1/1/2222']
# expected output
expected = [13, 13, 13, 15, 15, 17, 17]
# print some results
for d, e in zip(test_dates, expected):
    print(find_result(string, d), e)
```

Note: this method uses binary search to find the right value in the list of date boundaries. If there are only ever going to be about 3 dates in that list, then maybe you want to do a simpler loop that just goes through the dates, checking to see when the date is smaller that the target date. Binary search may be slower when you only have a list length of 2 or 3, but it will certainly be faster when the list is longer.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot @nullromo.
Really appreciate the help :)